# How do I connect a TV with an ethernet connection to a wifi network?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a TV with Ethernet port in one room and a wifi router in another. I want to connect my TV to internet, but i cant find any wifi adapter for my purposes. Can anybode help?
TV is Sony z5500

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Wireless Bridge. There used to be loads of them, but I haven't seen any in ages.

Without knowing your location, I cannot really recommend any brands/products, however hopefully this pushes you in the right direction!

You may also want to take a look at [HomePlug](http://www.homeplug.org) based devices which allow you to pass ethernet over your power lines.... Can be a lot more reliable than wireless.

Comment: Thank you. Location is Russian Federation, Rostov-on-Don. Router is DLink dl524

Comment: Ok, I really do not know any manufacturers there are in Russia so I can't help you further. Hopefully by saying Wireless Bridge and Homeplug I have put you in the right direction and you can search your favourite manufacturer for one of these devices.

Comment: You helpt me really much. I'm very greatful to you. I cant rate your message, sorry for that

Comment: Who gave -1?...

Comment: I'm going to +1 you just for the HomePlug suggestion, that should be an easy/cheap solution!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a wireless ethernet bridge. Example hardware is http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/products/WET610N

Depending on your main wifi router you might also be able to get everything to work using an Apple Airport Express

Answer (score 2):

In addition, many wireless routers can be set up to run as a bridge nodes.  I have a couple of old routers from LinkSys and DLink which I use as wireless bridge nodes.  Check the router's documentation to see if it supports operating as a bridge node.

Comment: any access point is capable of being a client bridge, most just don't have the settings for it.  reflash the device with dd-wrt or openwrt and you'll be able to do whatever you  want with it.